# Use a field value to update another field in same document

Tags: java, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am using Firebase Firestore and have documents with two fields:

```
field X
field Y
```

They are both numbers. Now I want to copy the value from X to Y. Of course I can just read the document to have the value X and then do a write operation on the same document and update field Y.

My question is, if there is a possibility to do this with just an update-operation as I couldn't find anything related but it seems to me like this might be something that's implemented by Firebase.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, something like you described is not possible. One would simply read the document and update it with the read value.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your needs, you can use transactions. For instance, I used it for the rating functionality, and actually, you might find [this thread](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/aggregation)  helpful.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).